# How to deal with the 9-bit strings in PDF files?

Tags: c++, pdf, encoding

In PDF files, the datatype string has 9-bit characters. While hex encoded strings are only 8-bit, it is possible in "normal" strings, to express 512 different different values for a single character. This is achieved using the octal representation of the character after a backslash.

When parsing PDF files, what datatype should I use to store such strings in? It's really annoying because I can't handle them like a byte array on which I later apply an encoding like utf-8, but I also can't use it as an already decoded string because 512 different characters are not enough to store unicode characters, so those 9-bit strings again need to get encoded somehow :/ I just don't know any encodings that encode / decode from/to 9-bit "bytes"...

Do you have any tips/ best practices on this?

**Update**

As R.Martinho Fernandes pointed out:

Event if it theoretically is possible to express values up to 512 with 3 octal digits, it is only valid to express values smaller than 256. The only strange thing about it is, why did they use a 3-digit-octal representation and not just a 2-digit-hex representation?

I think the answer to it is, that \b and \f would then be treated as hex-values. But I'm not sure about this.

Anyway: I'm glad the guys at adobe were not drunk when they made the PDF format :) AND: I need an answer to accept guys!

Comment: What is the meaning of, say, one 257 (0x101) in such a string?

Comment: That's a good question. I actually don't know it for sure...

Comment: Erm, there's no way to solve your problem without that information.

Comment: I think once you understand how the format works, you'll also understand how to deal with it. Out of the blue, this question doesn't seem very edifying.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Isn't understanding how to handle the strings a part of understanding how the format works?

Comment: @VanCoding: No. Understanding a format means you know what the *meaning* of the serialized data is. When you know the meaning, it should be very easy to write code to express the same information in different representations.

Comment: Where did you read this, btw? I hadn't heard this before, and double checking the spec tells me nothing as such.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Finding this out is actually part of the question :/

Comment: There are ASCII strings (7-bit, but one bit is wasted so 8-bit), byte strings (8-bit), UTF-16BE strings (8-bit), and PDFDocEncoded strings (8-bit). This 9-bit thing is nonsense.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes `The \ddd escape sequence provides a way to represent characters outside the
printable ASCII character set. For example:
(This string contains \245two octal characters\307.)` In the version 1.6 reference of adobe, it's on page 31.

Comment: The ASCII character set goes from 0-127. \245 is 165 decimal, and \307 is 199 decimal, both representable with 8 bits. \400 is not valid.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes AHH! Where did you read that it is not valid? If values < 256 are not valid, then it all makes sense.. My logical thought was that since there are 3 octal digits, it's possible to exceed 256

Comment: It is implied further down under "However, any 8-bit value may appear in a string." (I am reading from ISO32000-1 or PDF1.7; I don't think this changed), and is a direct conclusion of the only allowed encodings for strings being all 8-bit encodings. The octal notation has some waste, that's all (this practice is in common usage throughout the industry; see C++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cb8703691c736dd6af0f93dab2b3361f-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thanks for pointing this out! Please add it as anwer so I can accept it :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PDF format only allows strings of 8-bit bytes. Octal escapes could represent 9-bit units, but the 9th possible bit is useless for representing 8-bit bytes. This is common practice the same is true for C++ octal escapes for example. So, worry not, there are no 9-bit strings in PDF :)

Comment: This being said, PDF does know multiple-byte character encodings, cf. the section "Composite Fonts" in the PDF specification... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not really pressed for memory space, why not simply use a 16-bit type?